# Periodic ARP messages from Android device every 30-45 seconds.

Tags: android, c, sockets, arp

I have a native C application on an Android 4.3 device which transmits and receives data via UDP.

I noticed that the device is sending out ARP messages every 30-45 seconds while data are being actively transmitted/received via UDP to/from a remote IP address.

I would expect that as long as data are being exchanged actively there wouldn't be a need for sending out ARP messages as a cache is maintained. However, that doesn't seem to be the case.

Is this default and expected behavior on Android ?

Is there some configurable option when creating a socket which controls the frequency of these ARP messages?

Comment: Give a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532654/android-arp-clearing-time

Comment: It doesn't answer my question - but thanks for the link